# crystalreports in vs2005

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to create a crystal report that shows the address label of the employee, By using crystal reports in vs2005 I had created the crystal report and connect to the data source and every thing goes fine and the report generated correctly, it displays like

```
name

father name

address1                        address2                       city

state                           pin.
```

in the above format the report was generated. a single employee address in a single section

But my client want

```
name(of first employee)                         name(second employee)
fathername                                      fathername

address1                                        address1
address2                                        address2

city                                            city 

state                                           state

pin                                             pin
```

againg below third employee and fouth employees address label should generate. Can any one help me how to generate report in the fashion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont know how it can be done using crystal report ...

Comment: in report only I mean one section should show two employees details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click in the details section, select Section Expert.

Check the tick box "Format with multiple Columns". A new tab should appear after Color.

Using the settings on this tab, can generated columned data.

BASED ON OP COMMENT:

What need to do is:

Add the fields to the report (if planning 2 columns, use only the left half of the report, 3 columns only left third, and so forth).

Right click details and select section expert.

Check Format with Multiple Columns, this should show the Layout tab next to Color tab.

For this example, under Layout tab, Change Printing Direction from Down then across to across then Down. Change Detail size to half of the Report width.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and stumbled across this question. I tried all but  none of the suggestions worked. Not sure how you managed to solve it.

Im posting a solution that worked for me. Hope it would help anyone arriving here.

When you add a new report, please select "Use the Report wizard option" and select "Mail Label" option in the "Choose an Expert" tab as below.

In the following pages, choose your appropriate data Source and select "User defined Label"
and specify your height and width. 
Play with these options to get the optimal number of employees per page and this should create a report as per your requirement.

Hope that helps.