# crystal report to print details of employees side by side

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to create a crystal report that shows the address label of the employee, By using crystal reports in vs2005 I had created the crystal report and connect to the data source and every thing goes fine and the report generated correctly, it displays like

Ashok(1st emp)

Station Road

Hyderabd

.........

Kiran(2nd emp)

Air port road

Mumbai

..........

Ravi (3rd emp)

address1

address2

............

suresh 4th emp)

add1

add2

etc in the linear way only but i want side by side of two employee details like

...............

Ashok(1st employee).................................Kiran(second employee)

Station Road..............................................Air port Road

Hyderabd........................................... .......Mumbai

etc.

Ravi(3rd employee)...................................Suresh(4th employee)

Address1...................................................Address1

Address2..................................................Address2

Thnks in advance

Right click in the details section, select Section Expert.

Check the tick box "Format with multiple Columns". A new tab should appear after Color.

Using the settings on this tab you can generated columned data.

Yesterday I had spent a lot of time time with the sol you provided, but I am unable to see the report in my desired format again all the results are coming one under one, But I want first emp details side second emp details down thrid emp details side of third emp fourth emp details, I am suffering a lot with this problem, All the project was completed, But I was stuck with this small problem on just printing the report. Please Help Me, Regards

Comment: Stop creating duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824028/crystalreports-in-vs2005

Comment: Again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824088/crystal-reports-in-vs2005

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click in the details section, select Section Expert.

Check the tick box "Format with multiple Columns". A new tab should appear after Color.

Using the settings on this tab you can generated columned data.

BASED ON OP COMMENT:

What you need to do is:

1. Add the fields to the report (if you are planning 2 columns, use only yhe left half of the report, 3 columns only left third, and so forth).
2. Right click details and select section expert.
3. Check Format with Multiple Columns, this should show the Layout tab next to Color tab.
4. For your example, under Layout tab, Change Printing Direction from Down then across to across then Down. Change Detail size to half of the Report width.

That should be it.

Comment: Hi Astander.. Yesterday I had spent a lot of time time with the sol you provided, but I am unable to see the report in my desired format again all the results are coming one under one, But I want first emp details side second emp details down thrid emp details side of third emp fourth emp details, I am suffering a lot with this problem, All the project was completed, But I was stuck with this small problem on just printing the report.

Please Help Me, 

Regards